# How to set Request and response "Content-Type" to "application/json;charset=UTF-8"?

Tags: python, json, request, httpresponse, flask-restful

In flask restful, based on open API spec, I need to ensure that requests have header `Content-Type` set to `application/json;charset=UTF-8` which means that input request is a JSON and encoded in UTF-8.

I can check for JSON using below code:

```
if request.is_json:
    do some thing
```

But, how can I make sure that request and response is `UTF-8` encoded and output should also be `application/json;charset=UTF-8` ?

Comment: Do you want to make sure that JSON character encoding is done with `UTF-8` ? Or you just want to make sure that `request` and `response` have `Content-Type` set to `application/json;charset=UTF-8` ?

Comment: I want to make sure that JSON character encoding is done with UTF-8 and also I have to make sure that the response has `Content-Type` set to `application/json;charset=UTF-8` in Flask-Restful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a response using  jsonify

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
...
```

Then you can change some http properties

```
response = jsonify({"status": "ok" })
response.status_code = 200
response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
return response
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set `JSONIFY_MIMETYPE` config to `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` like this.

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["JSON_AS_ASCII"] = False
app.config["JSONIFY_MIMETYPE"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

So next time, you return data like this `return jsonify(data)` - without messing with `response.headers`